# Show specific products via Widget on CMS page - but not by utilizing a category for it

Tags: magento-1.9

We want to display specific products that the user can choose in the backend of Magento (1.9). Right now we know that there is:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="xxx" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

for displaying a specific category, but what I do want is to determine the specific products and show them in the same manner.

Like:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" product_ids="22, 23, 32, 942, 1283" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Note the difference: **`product_ids="22, 23, 32, 942, 1283"`**.

How can I achieve this? Is this even possible? What would be needed to enable it for my shop?

Answer (score 0):

[Magento Multi Products Widget](https://github.com/dio5/magento-multiproducts-widget/)

this will probably solve your problem